# How Do I get the current instance from an AppDomain?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, plugins, appdomain

I use the default appdomain (AD) which I use to create new appdomains (AD1) when required for running plugins in isolation.
When creating the new domain I also wire up the AppDomainUnload event to allow me to call clean up code etc.

The issue I seem to have is:

1) Create AD1 from AD

2) Run code in AD1

3) Call AD.Unload(AD1)

The code switches to AD1 and calls the unloading event passing in a reference to the current AppDomain (AD1).

At this point I'd like to get a reference to the current instance running in AD1 to call a shutdown method however there is no GetInstance on the AppDomain class.

Any ideas how I can go about getting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the instance in AD1, you could either store the instance in a static variable in the AppDoman, statics are scoped to the AppDomain. Alternatively if this is not a singleton type object, you can maintain a List<> of the objects in the AppDomain.

You could put this "registration" in the constructor of your plug-in instance. When handling the Unload you can use either the static or enumerate the list and perform the required clean-up on the object(s).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [AppDomain.CurrentDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.currentdomain.aspx)?

Comment: This thread is a perfect answer to Kirill's question about whether or not we ever run into each other on SO.  He's sitting next to me.

Comment: I'm sure it happens the opposite way round just as often :)

Comment: Ha ha, Jared typed in his answer, hit refresh and bang! :)

Comment: Don't think so as I already know which domain I'm in as it's passed as an argument to the AppDomainUnload that the code runs. So whilst I know the domain I can't get a handle to the running instance of my plugin.

Comment: @Spanners: Ah, so you're not after the instance of the *domain*, you're after the instance of some other type? What guarantee is there that you'll only have one instance *of* that type within the domain? Could you use a static variable? (There's effectively a separate static variable per AppDomain.) Better still, could the plug-in creation code not register the clean-up handler itself? It obviously knows the instance it's created...

Comment: Hadn't thought of it like that.  Thanks Jon!